# Executing the shell command in QProcess.Piping the input

Tags: c++, qt, shell, batch-file, qprocess

I am trying to pipe the commands and execute it, but I am not able to figure how to pipe it.
I am trying to copy multiple files at once using the shell command

> for %I in (source) do copy %I (destination)

```
QString files = "for %I in (source) do copy %I (destination)"
QProcess copy ;
copy.start(files);
```

I have to implement the piping to do that. 
for Eg.

```
QProcess sh;
sh.start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << "ifconfig | grep inet");

sh.waitForFinished();
QByteArray output = sh.readAll();
sh.close();
```

How can I implement piping for my copy process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Piping (or command chaining) with QProcess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901884/piping-or-command-chaining-with-qprocess)

Comment: @Azeem those answers are not helping me .

Comment: Errors? Issues?

Comment: QProcess shows no status , it just not copying . i guess i am not doing the chaining properly.

Comment: Why use an external process to copy the files rather than simply use [`QFile::copy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#copy-1)?  Just create another  thread on which to invoke `QFile::copy` and use signals/slots to notify of any errors or state changes etc.

Comment: @G.M. I have used that, even that also makes some lagging issues in my application. using shell script doesn't create any hassles.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
QProcess sh;
sh.start( "sh", { "-c", "ifconfig | grep inet" } );

if ( !sh.waitForFinished( -1 ) )
{
    qDebug() << "Error:" << sh.readAllStandardError();
    return -1;
}

const auto output = sh.readAllStandardOutput();
// ...
```

`waitForFinished()` should be called in blocking mode and it must be checked if it was successful or not.

Comment: i tried
    d->copyProcess->start( "sh" , QStringList() << "-c" << files);
    if(!d->copyProcess->waitForFinished(-1))
    {
        qDebug()<< "Error is there" << d->copyProcess->readAllStandardError();
    }
console =  Error is there  ""

Comment: @ninacheek: So, the command doesn't return anything on `stderr` but there was an error. Did you try to run the command without pipe? Does that run successfully?

Comment: @ninacheek: What is `files`? What are its values?

Comment: files is a string which contains  the list of files to be copied and the folder where it has to copy

Comment: @ninacheek: Can you try without pipe e.g. `start( "sh", { "-c", "ls" } );`?